# How to package a war with an external manifest.yml

Tags: grails, war, manifest, cloud-foundry

I am using a grails app that will be deployed to CloudFoundry. CloudFoundry uses manifest.yml file at the root of the directory. This file is picked up by CF when pushing the application.

Is it possible for me to pass this manifest.yml externally? When I ship my WAR file to the client, I don't want to ship the manifest.yml that I had been using in development and wouldn't expect the client to rebuild the application with their version of manifest.yml

Does CF support passing in a manifest.yml that is external to the WAR file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "pass the manifest file externally."  Couldn't you ship your customer a WAR file plus a sort of template of your manifest, asking the customer to simply fill in things that are specific to their environment, e.g. credentials?

Comment: The manifest is part of the WAR file, right? So if I ship a WAR file to the customer and they need to change somethings (e.g. credentials) in the manifest.yml...how will they do it? Extract the WAR, change the manifest.yml, and package it again? that seems highly inefficient from code shipping perspective.

Comment: Here is a scenario: My app uses a third party webservice and so it requires a URL for that webservice. I pass in the value of this URL as user defined environment variable in `manifest.yml`. I package the application and send one file (the WAR file) to the client. At the client site the URL of the third part app is slightly different. What does the client do? OR does CF assume that it is my job as an application developer to ship with production values? externalizing these types of files is common practice.

Comment: The manifest is generally not part of the WAR file, unless I'm mistaken.  `cf push --help` shows separate flags you can pass to `cf push` for `-p: Path to app directory or to a zip file of the contents of the app directory` and `-f: Path to manifest`.  If you manifest happens to be in the same directory as your source, it might inadvertently end up in your WAR file as well, but I think that's just coincidental.

Comment: Amit is right - manifest.yml is not typically included in the war file. manifest.yml is only used by the cf CLI on the client. The CF platform has no knowledge of the file and will not look for it in a pushed app archive. You should ship the war file and the manifest.yml file separately.

Answer (score 0):

> CloudFoundry uses manifest.yml file at the root of the directory. This file is picked up by CF when pushing the application.

This is not correct.  The cf cli will pick up a `manifest.yml` file in the current directory if it exists.  That is the default location.  You can also specify a location with `cf push -f path/to/manifest.yml`.

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#find-manifest

> Is it possible for me to pass this manifest.yml externally?

This is the only way to do it.  Unless you want to put a `manifest.yml` in the WAR file, have your user run `unzip` and extract the file.  The `cf` cli will not look inside your WAR file for `manifest.yml`.  It may not even be able to find your WAR file without the `path` entry from `manifest.yml`.

> Does CF support passing in a manifest.yml that is external to the WAR file?

The platform doesn't offer any functionality around sharing manifest.yml files.  How you get this to your customer is up to you.

As mentioned in the comments above, you would likely want to ship a template of a functional `manifest.yml` to your customer or provide instructions on how the customer would create a `manifest.yml`.  It's likely going to differ in the customer's environment.  For example, they might want different host & domain names or they may bind different services.

Another option would be to ship a deployment script.  The deployment script, while more complicated, could be a little more intelligent as it could query for information using `cf` and attempt to setup more things automatically.  For example, does your app need a service?  A deployment script to create one automatically, which is something you cannot do with a `manifest.yml` file (it can only bind existing services).

Hope that helps!